# Unable to get the correct group by expression

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using Mysql for querying the database. I have a fruits table and I have written a query to fetch the amt at which the fruit is sold in a particular month. My query is as folows,

```
 select fruit_code, fruit_name, yyyymm, amt from fruits;
```

and it returns a result set of the below type

```
     fruit_code |  fruit_name | yyyymm | amt
    -----------------------------------------
     A          |  Apple      | 201401 | 100
     A          |  Apple      | 201402 | 150
     A          |  Apple      | 201403 | 200
     A          |  Apple      | 201403 | 170
```

but I want is that amt values should get added if the yyyymm is same. So I tried this below query

```
 select fruit_code, fruit_name, yyyymm, SUM(amt) from fruits group by yyyymm;
```

But it gives me this

```
  fruit_code | fruit_name | yyyymm | amt
  ----------------------------------------
   A         |   Apple    | 201401 | 570
```

Here all the values in the amt column got added and only one row gets returned.

what I need is a resultset like the one below

```
    fruit_code | fruit_name | yyyymm | amt
   ----------------------------------------
     A        |   Apple    |  201401 | 100
     A        |   Apple    |  201402 | 150
     A        |   Apple    |  201403 | 370
```

I can't quite figure out where i am going wrong. Please suugest me with the correct group by expression.

Comment: Your approach seems correct. Can you make a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) which reproduces the problem?

Comment: Try `group by fruit_code, fruit_name, yyyymm`

Comment: sweetu514 Like @Vatev, I question the veracity of your proposition.

Comment: It works correctly for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ab25/1

Comment: @mjsqu you are correct, but for this example (apples only) there seems to be some other problem.

Comment: What if there are extra fruits, what do you want to see in this case?

Answer (score 2):

With `select fruit_code, fruit_name, yyyymm, SUM(amt) from fruits group by yyyymm;` you are using a MySQL enhancement to the SQL Standard.

You are grouping by yyyymm and you are asking the dbms to give you:

- the yyyymm
- the sum of all amt for that yyyymm, no matter what fruit
- one of the fruit_codes where a record matches the yyyymm
- one of the fruit_names where a record matches the yyyymm

What you probably want is:

```
select fruit_code, fruit_name, yyyymm, SUM(amt)
from fruits 
group by fruit_code, fruit_name, yyyymm;
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
  select distinct c.code,c.fname,b.* from
  (
  select yyyymm,sum(amt) from d3 group by yyyymm
  )b,d3 c
  where b.yyyymm=c.yyyymm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query,

```
select fruit_code, fruit_name, yyyymm, SUM(amt) amt 
FROM fruits 
GROUP BY yyyymm,fruit_code, fruit_name
```

works for me